# Why am I returning only one of the filtered objects instead of all of them?

Tags: javascript

Write a function getPeopleBornIn which takes in an array and string month, and returns a new array of people and their birthday information who were all born in the given month.

```
function getPeopleBornIn(staff, month) {
 for (var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
     if (staff[i].birthDay.month === month) {
         var filteredInfo = staff[i];
     }
 }
 return `${filteredInfo.name.first} ${filteredInfo.name.last}: ${filteredInfo.birthDay.month} ${filteredInfo.birthDay.day}, ${filteredInfo.birthDay.year}`;
}

var staff = [
  {name: {first: "Alyssa", last: "Hacker"}, birthDay: {month: "June", day: 5, year: 1987}},
  {name: {first: "Ben", last: "Bitdiddle"}, birthDay: {month: "August", day: 19, year: 1984}},
  {name: {first: "Eva", last: "Ator"}, birthDay: {month: "March", day: 29, year: 1980}},
  {name: {first: "Lem", last: "Tweakit"}, birthDay: {month: "August", day: 11, year: 1989}},
  {name: {first: "Louis", last: "Reasoner"}, birthDay: {month: "November", day: 17, year: 1992}}
];
console.log(getPeopleBornIn(staff, 'August'));
//output: ["Ben Bitdiddle: August 19, 1984", "Lem Tweakit: August 11, 1989"]
```

Comment: `getPeopleBornIn` isn't returning more than one thing - consider using `Array#filter`.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

In your `for` loop, `var filteredInfo` is overwritten every loop, which returns only the last element that satisfies the condition. If you want to return several elements at one time, `filteredInfo` should be an array.

### Solution

#### For loop

```js
function getPeopleBornIn(staff, month) {
  // Make an empty array
  var filteredInfo = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
    // When birthDay.month is equal to month
    if (staff[i].birthDay.month === month) {
      // Put a string into the array
      filteredInfo.push(`${staff[i].name.first} ${staff[i].name.last}: ${staff[i].birthDay.month} ${staff[i].birthDay.day}, ${staff[i].birthDay.year}`);
    }
  }

  // Return the array
  return filteredInfo;
}

var staff = [{
    name: {
      first: "Alyssa",
      last: "Hacker"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "June",
      day: 5,
      year: 1987
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Ben",
      last: "Bitdiddle"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "August",
      day: 19,
      year: 1984
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Eva",
      last: "Ator"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "March",
      day: 29,
      year: 1980
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Lem",
      last: "Tweakit"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "August",
      day: 11,
      year: 1989
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Louis",
      last: "Reasoner"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "November",
      day: 17,
      year: 1992
    }
  }
];

console.log(getPeopleBornIn(staff, 'August'));
//output: ["Ben Bitdiddle: August 19, 1984", "Lem Tweakit: August 11, 1989"]
```

#### .filter() and .map()

```js
function getPeopleBornIn(staff, month) {
  // .filter(): Keep only elements that birthDay.month === month (Remove others)
  // .map(): Change each object to a string 
  return staff
    .filter(person => person.birthDay.month === month)
    .map(person => `${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}: ${person.birthDay.month} ${person.birthDay.day}, ${person.birthDay.year}`);
}

var staff = [{
    name: {
      first: "Alyssa",
      last: "Hacker"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "June",
      day: 5,
      year: 1987
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Ben",
      last: "Bitdiddle"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "August",
      day: 19,
      year: 1984
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Eva",
      last: "Ator"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "March",
      day: 29,
      year: 1980
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Lem",
      last: "Tweakit"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "August",
      day: 11,
      year: 1989
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "Louis",
      last: "Reasoner"
    },
    birthDay: {
      month: "November",
      day: 17,
      year: 1992
    }
  }
];

console.log(getPeopleBornIn(staff, 'August'));
//output: ["Ben Bitdiddle: August 19, 1984", "Lem Tweakit: August 11, 1989"]
```